# Why LastPass logs me out periodically?

Tags: password-management, lastpass

I'm using LastPass password manager extension in Google Chrome. I have to input your MASTER password (LastPass's password) to login and get all the functionality of the manager such as autofill passwords and users in multiple sites, etc.

This login lasts for probably an hour but then after coming back I have to input my master password again because it's logged out. I don't understand, shouldn't LastPass keep a cookie or something (sorry, I'm ignorant) to save the login. Why can LastPass save login for an hour, but not a week? Does some certificate expire? Or is there something wrong with my situation?

Addendum info: If I close Chrome and reopen after 5 seconds, LastPass logins automatically without me entering the password.

Comment: You should contact LastPass for this.

Comment: Contacting LastPass is largely a waste of time IMO. They keep telling me to disable cookie deletion to prevent the problem — which is of course unacceptable because the settings are that way on purpose. On my own I tried putting in a exception for "lastpass.com" which seemed to help, but only works part of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several different factors might influence LastPass state:

- Automatic logging out is a feature of LastPass that is intended to protect user passwords.

  The idea being that a computer left without attention for a long time might indicate it was compromised. As LastPass has no other way of telling who is using the computer, it checks asking for password (which by definition is known only by the right person).

  Depending on other protection mechanisms that user employs (for example physical protection), users can alter the time after which they are logged out in LastPass' Preferences. For Chrome the options are:

  - Automatically Log out when all browsers are closed and Chrome has been closed for (mins)
  - Automatically Log out after idle (mins)

  These settings might be set differently for different machines (like having a large timeout on a desktop computer kept inside your home and a short one on a laptop you take to a cafeteria).
- Cleaning cookies on a browser might cause LastPass to log out, as explained [here](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=395). You could observe a conflict with other plugins (so you should try troubleshooting by disabling all Chrome extensions except LastPass)
- LastPass has an option to keep browser logon state kept synced across different browsers (Preferences -> Advanced -> Share login state between other browsers) which might influence the experience. Particularly if one browser experienced problems and got logged out, it might force logging out other browsers.
- Lastly you might experience a technical issue that qualifies for contacting LastPass' support as explained here: [LastPass logs off almost immediately after I login?](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=4626)

Comment: Excelent idea! To respond your comment and answer, both boxes "automatically log out " in preferences are unchecked, and the textbox for number of minutes is empty.

Comment: You gave me lot of great ideas to continue, this helps me so I accept it! (I'm not sure if it will actually solve the problem, but the advice is to accept when they show you some progress).